# Merge two XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to create an excel.

I am running the excel generation program as a servlet. Whenever I am need to create an excel with huge data I am getting an out of memory error in the tomcat servlet ( I could not increase the heap size due to memory constraints).

I did a memory analysis using Eclipse Memory analyzer and I could not find a suspect and find that it's not a memory leak. Therefore I think in case of big file I could split the input and create two files ( in 2 requests) and merge them later.

Is it possible to do a merging of XSSFWorkbook? Can some body pleas point to a example?

Comment: can you do this?
Generate excel from a different standalone program?
Or you want the excel generation from the servlet itself?

Comment: Use https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html instead of XSSFWorkbook - you can create one workbook with much less memory.

Comment: @PJFanning thanks. I will have a look

Comment: @Shreyas Thanks for having a look. From servlet but as in 2 or 3 chunks

Comment: yeah... as @nantitv mentioned, try the streaming XSSFWorkbook class.
Would be eager to see some code/issues when you make progress with that.